# How to define an extension method in a scriptcs csx script

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, scriptcs

I'm playing with [ScriptCS](http://scriptcs.net/) (which is awesome!) but I couldn't figure out **how to define an extension method within a .csx script file**.

Take this example:

```
using System.IO;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Remove(this string source, params string[] toRemove)
    {
        foreach(var r in toRemove)
        {
            source = source.Replace(r,"");
        }
        return source;
    }
}

string[] entries = 
    Directory
        .GetFiles(
            @"C:\Users\blah\blah",
            "*.mp4",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select( p => p.Remove("Users"))
    .ToArray();

foreach(var e in entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

This yields the error:

> error CS1109: Extension methods must be defined in a top level static
>   class; Extensions is a nested class

I'm guessing that ScriptCS wraps the csx in some class which is causing extensions to be nested, is there any way around this?

Comment: This is a limitation in Roslyn. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/7c0a18eb-d37a-40e2-a26c-edb59b8f5cf3/. So currently you can't define extension methods in `.csx` files. You need to put them in a dll and reference that the dll.

Comment: @nemesv this looks answer-worthy =) Thank you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285150/how-do-you-have-shared-extension-methods-in-azure-functions-without-nesting-clas

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I feel your pain.

Actually this is a limitation of Roslyn currently as it wraps everything into a class even if it is another class.

I've talked to the Roslyn team however and they are going to support extension methods soon.

Comment: Run into this issue 3 years later: how should we interpret the word "soon"?

Comment: That's a great question. We're about to update to the latest version of Roslyn (2.0). I'll find out if that has added support for extension methods within csx.

Comment: Update on this. I confirmed in the latest Roslyn, top level extension methods are supported, so we should be able to get this to work for scriptcs when we release on Roslyn 2.0 (which should be months hopefully)

Answer (score 13):

Good news! It is **now supported** in C# script files (.csx)

But you have to declare an extension method **on top level**:

```
static string MyToLowerExtension(this string str)
{
    return str.ToLower();
}
```

**Do not** declare it in a static class:

```
// this will not work!
public static class MyExtensionsClass
{
    static string MyToLowerExtension(this string str)
    {
        return str.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Comment: tried a couple of times. didnt work. can you give an complete sample and versions of scriptcs and used framework?

Comment: @Chris sorry, I thought the question was about c# script (like c# Interactive window in Visual Studio), but now I see it's regarding some other technology

Comment: Well, how do you make it run? (Console please)

Comment: sorry, I don't know how about CLI. I prefer Visual Studio. It is under View menu - Other windows - C# Interactive

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, because compiling something on the fly requires a class, `scriptcs` was designed to take the raw code that **mattered** and wrap it in a class. You would need to modify a version of `scriptcs` for your needs -or consider [contributing to the project](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs).

However, I too **love** `scriptcs` and think it's one of the most fantastic projects out there today!

I too tried this early on when using `scriptcs` and my heart broke when it didn't work. If I had more bandwidth I'd contribute this addition on my own.

AFAIK this is not a limitation with Roslyn.

Comment: It is a limitation in the Roslyn scripting API.