# How do you have shared extension methods in Azure Functions without nesting classes?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, azure-functions

I know how to include other `.csx` files via `#load`.  However, extension methods have to be defined in a top-level class, and `#load` nests the class, so it's not top-level and the function throws a compilation error.

How do I use shared code without having it nest inside the function's post-compiled class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to correctly include extension methods for Azure Function you can use a #load as in all other cases, the only difference regarding the requirement that the extension methods needs to be in a top level class is to make them a top level methods :). When Azure Function gets compiled contents of csx files are being wrapped in a auto-created class, that's why it complains that extension methods written in a regular c# way will be nested inside of that auto-created class.

When that is understood there is a simple trick to have extension methods in separate csx file and still have them defined in top-level class:

here's run.csx file

```
#load "extensions.csx"

public static void Run(TimerInfo timer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("test".MyToUpperExtension());
}
```

and extensions.csx

```
static string MyToUpperExtension(this string str)
{
    return str.ToUpper();
}

static string MyToLowerExtension(this string str)
{
    return str.ToLower();
}
```

As you see the only difference between regular extension methods is that you don't need to wrap them in a static class by yourself.

Comment: When I read this, I said, "If this works, I'll eat my hat." And then it worked. Thankfully, I am not wearing a hat.

Comment: Glad I could help without causing indigestion problems ;)

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to create your extension method in a separate c# class and add it to your function.

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp)

> If you need to reference a private assembly, you can upload the
>   assembly file into a bin folder relative to your function and
>   reference it by using the file name (e.g. #r "MyAssembly.dll"). For
>   information on how to upload files to your function folder, see the
>   following section on package management

.

Comment: I don't want to use an assembly. I just have a static class defined in a `.csx` file. I can include it, but it won't compile because the class gets nested.